# regenerate initramfs after moving boot partition

Tags: linux, initramfs-tools

I've recently moved my linux system from hdd to ssd. I managed to get it booting and everything was fine until I deleted old boot partitions from hdd. Now when I try to boot I end up in dracut shell with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxx doesn't exist` error, where `xxxxx` is UUID of my former `/boot` or `/boot/efi` partition (I'm not exactly sure which one is it since I no longer have them).

Now I need to regenerate initramfs to use the new partitions I cloned from hdd to ssd. I tried running `dracut --regenerate-all --force` from rescue boot but it didn't help.

I'm using Fedora 21, so how can I do it? Or is there problem in something else?

Answer (score 8):

Do you still have a F21  install media?

If so do the following:

boot to "troubleshooting" >  Rescue a Fedora System

Allow for mounting (normally not r/o)

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage 

dracut --regenerate-all -f && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

If you are *sure* it is not throwing errors on the `dracut --regenerate-all` previous  made  (i.e. `ls /boot` shows them but won't boot) just rebuild grub  with the second command.

~ Sent from a Fedora 22 box

Comment: That's basically what I did (although I ran dracut --regenerate-all -f from the rescue boot option that was installed), however it didn't help. I reinstalled now anyway as I realized that it's just not possible to ensure 100% compatibility when virtually anything could be relying on properties of the hdd (eg, UUIDs, partition names, partion sizes, ...) that's just not possible to reliably handle without deeper understaning.

Answer (score 1):

try the following link instructions:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/57752/how-do-i-regenerate-my-initramfs/

## scan for logical volumes first:

vgscan
vgchange -ay

## Find swap partitions:

blkid|grep swap

## and an example:

/dev/mapper/fedora-swap: UUID="28d71a2c-1b34-4115-aa19-083373ec4d8a" TYPE="swap"

Edit /etc/fstab to use the swap partition, here's an example:
 nano /etc/fstab

/dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

## To regenerate all initramfs, do:

dracut --regenerate-all --force

Answer (score 1):

I had fixed everything in fstab and grub entries and all, but still I was getting into maintenance mode at boot time with dracut time out errors:

```
dracut --regenerate-all -f && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This fixed my problem. (CentOS7 Dedicated Server)

Answer (score 0):

After removing swap partition from my CentOS7 machine, I got dracut time out errors. Regenerating initramfs and grub2 didn't solve.
In order to solve the issue I had to manually modify the grub2 configuration file:

```
## Look for swap in grub configuration file 

cat /boot/grub2/grub.cfg | grep swap

## Delete old swap
remove rd.lvm.lv=<lvm_name>/swap string from grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every time this happens, I boot to previous kernel and in Gnome's terminal remove and install kernel and related packages again. Note that the version string will be different, thus just look on currently installed kernel version via your distors preffered method. Below is example for Fedora 37 when it happened last time for me.

```
$ sudo dnf remove *6.2.9-200*
$ sudo dnf upgrade kernel --refresh
```

Few notes:

- It is not mandatory, but just to be sure the metadata and package
  managers cache is fresh, the " --refresh" switch is added. Feel free
  to remove it if conditions below does not apply.
- If you are fully
  sure and confident that you know that there is no newer kernel
  suddenly pushed or you are not using unstable/testing repo, add " -y"
  in the end of second command. It will accept changes for you; Reboot
  and you should be good.